# how to apply lastcolumn (and not lastrow) into a range?

Tags: excel, vba

```
lastcolumn = Sheet3.Cells(1, Sheet3.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Sheet3.Range("B17:" & lastcolumn & "17").Formula = "=SUMIFS($H:$H,$B:$B,B$1)"
```

it is not working :(

Comment: What does not working mean please?

Comment: your formula for **lastcolumn** is returning a ***number*** correctly................your range statement needs a ***letter***.

Comment: I am not sure how to apply the lastcolumn into the range statement

Comment: You can use Cells method and pass a number in as column argument.

Answer (score 1):

As QHar said, use

```
Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(17, 2), Sheet3.Cells(17, lastcolumn)). ...
```

Comment: Thank you Qhar & Chris!